# Trying to print the sum of each element of an 2d array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

My Project is creating a small table that shows the number of recovered cases of COVID there are in Canada across all provinces over a period of 8 months.

That is formatted in a 2D array where the vertical of the array represent cases each months and the horizontal represent each provinces

My goal is to find the sum of cases each month by sum of cases from all provinces

I have to create a nested for loop to compute the sum of the recovered persons in Canada for each month specified.

Therefore I have to add each index together in the for loop.

```
int[][] recovered = {{ 106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 866, 1001 },
{ 502, 615, 209, 947, 1106, 2634, 3178, 4445 },
{ 12, 26, 34, 18, 13, 30, 46, 52 },
{ 163, 203, 276, 308, 567, 729, 628, 765 }};
```

Above is my 2d array my goal is to sum all 0's together,1's together 2's together, and so on.

I have tried to make my for loop add the sum of each index together depending on the array's length but my outcome is not accurate.

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<recovered.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<recovered[i].length;j++) {
     sum+=recovered[i][j];
 }
System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output from this? Just one sum printed to the console or a sum per first-level index? For the former, move your `System.out.println(sum)` **down** one line. For the latter, move `int sum = 0` **down** one line

Answer (score 0):

You should be traversing your array vertically first then horizontally you.

This will give you the answer you look for

```
int sum=0;
for(int j=0; j<recovered[0].length;j++) {           
    for(int i=0; i<recovered.length;i++) {
            sum+=recovered[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;
    }
```

**EDIT**
The first conditional loop

```
for(int j=0; j<recovered[0].length;j++)
```

will use the length of the smaller array which is length of 8 in the example. Assuming that all your smaller arrays have the same length. You don't have to worry again looping using another variable. This will vertically traverse the second array.

The second conditional loop

```
for(int i=0; i<recovered.length;i++)
```

will check for how many "mini" array inside the array there are and start traversing the array horizontally i.e. traversing through each "mini" array.

One more detail that i see lacking from your code is that you don't set the `sum = 0` again after printing out the result. With that the above code that you have given. Simply add up all values of the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution could be to mapping all the values of the array into an IntStream and use the sum function. This makes the problem solved by a one-liner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] recovered = {{ 106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 866, 1001 },
            { 502, 615, 209, 947, 1106, 2634, 3178, 4445 },
            { 12, 26, 34, 18, 13, 30, 46, 52 },
            { 163, 203, 276, 308, 567, 729, 628, 765 }};

    final var result = Arrays.stream(recovered).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sum();

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your loops does is it will print sum of first 8 months, and then proceed to print sum of second 8 months and so on, So As you have told u want to display the sum month wise.
I would suggest you run the column loop as an outer loop and row loop as an inner loop,
like this.

```
for(int col=0; col < recovered[0].length; col++) {           
    int sum = 0;
    for(int row=0; row < recovered.length; row++) {
        sum+=recovered[row][col];
    }
System.out.println(sum);
}
```